# Grunt Sass - output errors to console?

Tags: google-chrome, sass, console.log, grunt-contrib-watch

Below is my grunt file, using **grunt-sass** and **grunt-contrib-watch** to 
compile my Sass. Is it possible to console log the error to chrome?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Sass to CSS
    sass: {
      app: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'wp-content/themes/bones/library/scss',
          src: ['*.scss'],
          dest: 'wp-content/themes/bones/library/css',
          ext: '.css'
        }],

      },
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        outputStyle: 'nested',
        imagePath: "../",
      }


    },

    watch: {
      sass: {
        files: ['wp-content/themes/bones/library/scss/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass']
      },
      options: {
        livereload: true,
        spawn: false
      }
    },
  });


  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');


      grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
    };
```

Comment: Any **error** that Sass would raise would be part of the compiled CSS and it would be possible to view it in the browser.

Comment: I know what you mean I have seen them before using normal sass compilers but this config does not seem to show them.